# C# Menu and SubMenu on Console-Troubles on Menu Return

Tags: c#, methods, menu

I am new at programming and I'm trying to create a Menu that has inside Submenus. The main Menu has all the options to procede while the submenu has a CRUD for each options inserted.

However the submenu I've done(Animals)doesn't work neither of the visualize by id methods and it goes like this to the following crud methods for the submenus. Also when a submenu complets its tasks it should return to the initial Submenu options, allowing to return to main Menu by pressing zero. Which is  not happening, though I tryied doing things differently. I'm not sure if it's the switch statement which wrong or if it's the methods call.

Sorry if the code is a little bigger than usual:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace menu
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int id = 1;
        enum animalHeader { id, name, client_name, type_animal };
        enum clientHeader { id, name, client_surname, adrress };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] animal = new string[20, 4];
            string[,] client = new string[20, 6];

            do { MenuOptions(animal); } while (true);

        }
        static void MenuOptions(string[,] animal)
        {
            int userChoice;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nChoose one of the following options:\n");

                Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Animals");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] Clients");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Quit application\n");

            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userChoice) || userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 2);

            Console.Clear();

            switch (userChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    menuAnimal(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //menuClient(client);
                    mainMenu();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again!!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void menuAnimal(string[,] animal)
        {
            int optAnimal;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nInsert one of the following options:\n");

                Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Insert animal");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] See animal");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 3 ] Alter animal");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 4 ] Erase animal");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 5 ] List animals");
                Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Return to main menu\n");

            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out optAnimal) || optAnimal < 0 || optAnimal > 5);

            Console.Clear();

            switch (optAnimal)
            {
                case 1:
                    insertData(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    visualizeByid(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    updateById(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    deleteByid(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    listData(animal);
                    menuReturn(animal);
                    break;

            }
        }
        static void mainMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void menuReturn(string[,] animal)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            do { menuAnimal(animal); } while (true);

        }

        static int generateId()
        {
            return id++;
        }
        static int getInsertIndex(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[j, 0])) return j;
            }

            return -1;
        }
        static void insertData(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int id = generateId();
            int n = getInsertIndex(matrix);

            matrix[n, 0] = Convert.ToString(id);

            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}: ");
                    matrix[n, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[n, j]));
            }
        }
        static int searchId(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int choosenId, index = -1;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Insert ID to continue: ");

            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choosenId));


            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(choosenId) == matrix[i, 0])
                {
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }
        static void visualizeByid(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);

            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Wrong Id"); }
        }
        static void updateById(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);
            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Insert {Enum.GetName(typeof(animalHeader), j)}:  ");
                        matrix[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Id does not exist"); }
        }
        static void deleteByid(string[,] matrix)
        {
            int pos = searchId(matrix);
            if (pos != -1)
            {
                for (int i = pos; i < pos + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        matrix[i, j] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("Id does not exist"); }
        }
        static void listData(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"\t{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I can spot is in the `menuAnimal` method. Check what happens when you enter 0, for example by stepping through the code with debugger.

When user enters 0, the first `do-while` condition passes (as 0 is a number and is not smaller than 0 and not larger than 5), but in the following `switch` statement you do not have a `case` for 0, so the method stops executing and just redraws, because execution continues to `menuReturn(animal);` in `MenuOptions`.

The next main problem here is the `menuReturn` method. Observe that once you get in this method, you can never "escape". It always redraws the animals menu whatever happens and `while(true)` ensures that it will happened indefinitely. Because there is no `break` condition inside, it will just keep on going.

### Different approach

I will suggest a different approach here, although there are many options you have, so you are free to use a different solution that suits you.

First get rid of the `menuReturn` method and put this "menu output loop within the menu methods themselves. In pseudo code this would be:

```
static void MenuMethod()
{
   while (true)
   {
      userInput = read user input for example using do..while as in original code   

      goBack = false
      switch (userInput)
      {
         case optionA: 
           doSomething();
           goBack = true; //set go back to true if you want go up a level
           break;
         case optionSubmenu:
           submenu(); //go to a submenu, which will start its own loop
           //after submenu is closed (goBack = true), execution will return to this level
           break;
      }
      if (goBack) return; //end execution of this menu
   }
}
```

So briefly in your case it could look like this:

```
static void MenuOptions(string[,] animal)
{
    while (true)
    { 
        int userChoice;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nChoose one of the following options:\n");

            Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Animals");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] Clients");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Quit application\n");

        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userChoice) || userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 2);

        Console.Clear();

        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                menuAnimal(animal);
                break;
            case 2:
                //menuClient(client);
                break;
            case 0:
                Environment.Exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Try again!!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Similar goes for animals menu:

```
static void MenuAnimal(string[,] animal)
{
    while ( true )
    {
        int optAnimal;

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nInsert one of the following options:\n");

            Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ] Insert animal");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ] See animal");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 3 ] Alter animal");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 4 ] Erase animal");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 5 ] List animals");
            Console.WriteLine("[ 0 ] Return to main menu\n");

        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out optAnimal) || optAnimal < 0 || optAnimal > 5);

        Console.Clear();
        bool goBack = false;
        switch (optAnimal)
        {
            case 1:
                insertData(animal);
                break;
            case 2:
                visualizeByid(animal);
                break;
            case 3:
                updateById(animal);
                break;
            case 4:
                deleteByid(animal);
                break;
            case 5:
                listData(animal);
                break;    
        }
        if ( goBack ) return;
    }
}
```